# why does 1st website access with url parameter not work, but 2nd does

Tags: asp.net, url, webforms

I have two separate cases where 3rd-party browser access to my website pages, involving argument passing, does not work the first time; but always work correctly on the 2nd (nth) try. For example:

I send a link to a user in an email, intending to access a specific blog post. An example is: `http://jimtellier.com/BlogJT1?pid=8`.
This should take the user directly to the 8th entry in the blog page; but the FIRST time it is used, the browser ends up at the `default.aspx` page. Again, 2nd time etc works as expected (closing the browser after the first attempt, BTW).

The second case is similar, but involves a bit more logic server-side: I send an email to a user, asking to confirm their intent/identity to create an account on my site. The link I provide looks something like this: `http://jimtellier.com/Login?id=2344a44ea3dd278f`, where `id` represents a validation key. Again, this scenario FAILS the first time the link is used, but re-trying the same link subsequently works fine.

In both of these scenarios, in the `Page_Load` method, I use `var ident = Request["pid"];` (or `["id"]`, in the Login case), with logic:

```cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var accesscode = Request["id"];
    if (accesscode != null && accesscode != "")
    {
        UserAccount uacct = null;
        if (ValidateUser(accesscode, ref uacct))
        {
            LoginUser(uacct, Context);
            Response.Redirect("BlogJT1.aspx");
        }
        else
            OutputLabel.Text = "Validation key expired.  Please retry sign-up!";
    }
    ... etc.
```

I'm not clear on a debug/diagnose strategy for this behavior. Since both cases work ok 2nd/nth time thru, the logic in `Page_Load` would seem to be correct, yes? Oh, BTW, if I try to replicate this in VS debug, once the browser has brought in the default page, specifically navigating to either of the `?arg=` cases works as expected; so debug frustration == 1. :) TIA for any ideas!

EDIT: A couple more data points: 1) same symptoms even if IIS has cached an instance of the site (due to other browser access ongoing), 2) same symptoms even if (this) browser is Not closed after 1st attempt (i.e. making 2nd use of the email link works in any case). I'm not seeing how I can get to default.aspx despite having specifically requested login.aspx or BlogJT1.aspx. Arrgh!

Comment: @GSerg - I'm sorry ,but I Completely do not understand your edit to my post.  For the most part, all of the "strike-outs" in the edits are replaced by Exactly the same content that I had originally written.   Besides that, you offered no assist whatsoever. Please explain!  Thank you for your time!

Comment: The most important part of the edit is the addition of the `webforms` tag which is the name of the technology you are using. Without it people who are proficient in this technology are likely to not see your question. The less important part of the edit is the establishing paragraphs from the original wall of text for readability and the markup of what should be formatted as code as code.